# Using the Importer on an IIS Server

Tags: import, iis

I'm running into an issue for a client whereby I keep getting the same error over and over again whilst trying to import an exported file (into an IIS environment):

```
Sorry, there has been an error. The uploaded file could not be moved to D:\www\www514\obtecfoundcom/wp-content/uploads/2011/04.
```

Anybody know what might be going on here (besides the weird slashes)? Thank you! Noel

**Technical Info**

http://wl17www502.webland.ch/php5/info.php

**Attempts so far**

Googled the hell out of the error, nothing with a real solution.

Permissions changed to 777 all the way up to /wp-content/ (recursive)

Manually adding the file to ../2011/04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you verified permissions on the upload_tmp_dir (C:\Temp)?  It's possible that the upload is actually failing there rather than in the destination directory.

Comment: And if C:\Temp is on an external location from where your WordPress is managing uploads, simply change that value in your php.ini  file to focus on the IIS location where permissions are granted for you.